# Connecting to a router from a java program on Linux

Tags: java, android, linux, sockets, raspberry-pi

I am developing a java app that starts by connecting to a router.
here is the code:

```
try {
    Service service = new Service(new JIPImpl(new PacketHandlerIPv6()));    
    JOtionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Service Created " );
    JenNetIPNetwork network = service.createNetwork(new InetSocketAddress("fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:32:54ff", 1873));
    Collection<Node> my_nodes = network.discoverNodes();

} catch (JipException e) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Couldn't connect To The Router, Error: "+ e.getMessage() );
    }
```

What i get is the first message : "Service Created" .
Then service.create isn't executed and the exception is thrown which gives me the message : Couldn't connect To the Router, Error: Timeout.

IT is worth noting that:
The EXACT SAME jar file WORKS PERFECTLY on windows 7 (where it is originally developed)
I only got that problem when i tried to run the jar file on Linux.

I had a similar problem when i built the same program on android, and it was solved when i added the internet permission to the manifest. Is there a similar permission that should be added to use the internet on Linux ?

Comment: try to telnet from your Linux box and see.

Comment: I suspect it's most likely a firewall configuration issue - check you can actually communicate between the Linux box and the router using the router manufacturer's software, or via a browser if the access is over a web interface.  Also worth checking the IPv6 settings in the Linux box -- ensure it has an address on the correct network and that appropriate routes are set up.

Comment: The web browsing works fine with the router, also pinging the router with its IPv4 works fine too . However, pinging with the above address (the ipv6 ) doesn't work !!! 
the result :
    ping: unknown host fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:32
Can it still be a firewall configuration issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your Linux box cannot reach the router and port 1873. Can you ping the router?

```
ping6 fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:32:54ff
```

Can you reach port 1873 of the router?

```
telnet fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:32:54ff 1873
```

With this last one you should get a response like this:

```
Trying fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:32:54ff...
Connected to fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:32:54ff.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Otherwise it seems the router + port is unreachable, possibly due to your firewall setup or network setup.

Actually the `ping6` is only for a very basic sanity check, it's not really important. ICMP packets might be blocked, causing it to fail, for example. the really important part is to get the `telnet` working, in order to confirm that your machine can reach both the host *and* the port. If this `telnet` works then the Java program should work too.

**UPDATE**

As you discovered yourself, ipv6 wasn't enabled. You can enable it with `modprod ipv6`, which will load the `ipv6` kernel module.

Next time it's good to mention that you're working on a raspberry pi, and the OS (rasbian?), as that might right a bell to many folks.

Comment: If i use ping with the IPv4 address of the same router , it works fine.
   ping 192.168.11.1

However, if i use the ping with the IPv6 :

    ping fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:32:54ff

It doesn't work.

Any idea why?

Comment: My bad, use `ping6` instead of `ping`. If you don't have `ping6` or it doesn't work, then there could be a problem with your `IPv6` setup.

Comment: using ping6 I get the following error

socket: Address family not supported by protocol.

It seems it is an IPv6 setup problem as you said, I'll search for how to solve it.

If you have an idea , it would be appreciated.
Thanks for you help

Comment: Well, the `telnet` is more important. ICMP packets might be blocked, and that's not a problem. Even if the `ping6` doesn't work , if the `telnet` does then the Java program should too.

Comment: Problem solved, the problem was that the ipv6 wasn't enabled. I am working on a raspberry pi by the way. So i found out that ipv6 should be enabled through the command : "modprobe ipv6"

Then it worked fine. 
Thank you @janos
Thank you all very much.

Comment: The OS is NOOBS (i bought the preloaded SD card). 
Sorry about not mentioning the RPI , i just thought presenting the problem as a Linux problem in general would be better.

Comment: @ShadyAhmed it's not a problem, it's for your benefit, for finding better results faster. For future reference ;-)